# How to restrict access to a specific file on iis windows 2012

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, web.config

IIS on Windows 2012 R2

A website has a number of directories and in one of those directories is restricted-page.html to which I want to restrict access to all except a particular windows user.

The rest of the site is to be freely browsable by anybody.

Following instructions at https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config I expected that putting the following web.config into the directory containing restricted-page.html would work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="restricted-page.html">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="windows-domain\account-name"/> 
         <deny users="*"/>                          // deny others
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="*">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

However, users can't browse into the containing directory without requiring authentication.

Could anyone advise?

Comment: Why don't you just use the normal NTFS file permissions? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815151/how-to-restrict-specific-users-from-gaining-access-to-specified-web-re

Comment: The `system.web` XML node only applies to ASP.NET files, it doesn't affect static html pages. That's why the page is still accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was as Broco says above and much easier than I'd supposed.
Disable Anonymous Authentication for the site in IIS
Enable Windows Authentication
Then use file permissions.

[step by step with screenshots](https://blog.stealthbits.com/how-to-secure-a-default-iis-site-enable-windows-authentication)